# I'm from Israel, do I need power adapters for Nepal?

Tags: power, nepal

I'm traveling to Nepal and I don't know if I need to bring power adapters and if so which power adapters to bring

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on which plugs you have.  The type H, which is the three sort of flat pins in a V shape, will need an adapter.  The type M the three round pins will work in some outlets.

Unfortunately Nepal uses several different sockets, so might be good to have an adapter to type C, the two round pin plug used in Europe.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great website that given a destination and a country of residence tells you the compatibilities or lack thereof of your plugs with their sockets:

[power-plugs-sockets.com/il/nepal](https://www.power-plugs-sockets.com/il/nepal/)

In your case it says:

> In Nepal, they use power sockets (outlets) of type C, D and M. In Israel, you have plugs C and H. You need a power plug adapter in Nepal for sockets type C, D and M.

> You don't need a voltage converter in Nepal.